# In Titus 2:13 is "that blessed hope" an allusion to Psalms 84:5?

Tags: psalms, eschatology, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, titus

> Brenton Septuagint Translation
>   Psalm 84:
>
> 1**For the end**, a Psalm for the sons of Core, concerning the wine-presses. How amiable are thy tabernacles, O Lord of hosts!
>   2**My soul longs, and faints for the courts of the Lord**: my heart and my flesh have exulted in the living god.
>   3Yea, the sparrow [IE: "the poor saint"] has found himself a home, and the turtle-dove a nest for herself, where she may lay her young, even thine altars, O Lord of hosts, my King, and my God.
>
> 4**Blessed** are they that **dwell in thy house**: they will praise thee evermore. Pause.
>   5**Blessed is the man whose help is of thee, O Lord; in his heart he has purposed to go up**
>   6the valley of weeping, **to the place which he has appointed**, for there the law-giver will grant **blessings**.
>   7They shall go from strength to strength: **the God of gods shall be seen in Sion**.
>
> 8O Lord God of hosts, hear my prayer: hearken, O God of Jacob. Pause.
>   9Behold, O God our defender, and look upon the face of thine anointed.
>   10For one day in thy courts is better than thousands. I would rather be an abject **in the house of God**, than dwell in the tents of sinners.
>   11For the Lord loves mercy and truth: God will give grace and glory: the Lord will not withhold good things from them that walk in innocence.
>
> 12O Lord of hosts, **blessed is the man that trusts in thee**.
>
> Brenton Septuagint Translation, 1884.

If this was the blessed hope, what was he hoping? Is it clear from this that it refers to "Heaven"? Could this be the kingdom of God on earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allusion, if one exists, is only of the most general kind; but I struggle to see much correlation.

Titus 2:13 says, "while we wait for the blessed hope--the appearing of the glory of our great God and Savior, Jesus Christ".  That is the object that is blessed is ***hope***.  By definition, that hope is a future event, at least at the time of the author, Paul.

In Psalm 84 the object that is consistently blessed is the person who "dwells in thy house" (present tense), or, "whose help is in the Lord", or, "whose trusts in thee", ie God.  Thus, Psalm 84 is discussing the present life of an individual who constantly lives in the presence of God by trusting and attending services at the temple.  The early verses may allude to a future heaven but that is not entirely clear - v4 appears to extolling the advantages of those who serve God in His presence in the heavenly courts 9in the present).  Such are immediately compared with mortals (v5) who live (as if in the presence of God) by trusting in God.  V6 makes this even clearer.

The ideas in Ps 84 are similar to the idea in Eph 2:6 where Paul discusses Christians as people who are seated (present tense) in heavenly places, precisely because were are saved by faith in Christ (v8-10).

Answer (score 0):

One should look first to the immediate context.   Hope is found in the introduction to the book at Titus 1:2 and identified with eternal life promised  by God the Father (see 1:3-4).  This hope of eternal life at Titus 3:7 is because God saved us through Jesus Christ (3:5-6).

This has implications for the interpretation of Titus 2:13 relative to the identification of God.

Since contextually "hope"  comes from two persons, God through Jesus in Titus,  there are two persons in view at 2:13 as well.